# I want to create a 2 column layout using float. But only the odd columns work perfectly not the even columns

Tags: html, css

```css
#one{
 float:left;
 background-color:red;
 width: 250px;
}

#two{
    float:left;
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 250px;
}

#three{
clear:both; 
background-color: pink;
width:250px;
}

#four{
 
 background-color: orange;
 width: 250px;
}

#five{
 float:left;
 background-color: purple;
 width: 250px;
}

#six{
 float:left;
 background-color: green;
 width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p id="one">Para 1</p>
<p id="two">Para 2</p>
<p id="three">Para 3</p>
<p id="four">Para 4</p>
<p id="five">Para 5</p>
<p id="six">Para 6</p>
```

I want to create a 2 column layout using float. But the float property works only with the odd columns. For the even columns, it doesn't work.If I want to extent the list suppose I want add more paragraphs then how would I do it.

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept? ... or it simply didn't work?

Comment: Since I didn't got any response I deleted my answer